# how to generate warning of non-null argument for my custom function?

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to write a library function where arguments should not be null, and want that gcc should generate warning if some one try to pass NULL. My code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int own_strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
        if( str1 == NULL || str2 == NULL){
            if(str1 == NULL && str2 == NULL) 
                return 0;
            else if( str1 == NULL)
                return str2[0];
            else
                return str1[0];
        }
        int i=0;
        while(str1[i] && str2[i]){
                if( str1[i] != str2[i]){
                        break;
                }
                i++;
        }
        return str1[i]-str2[i];
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        const char *str1 = "hello";
        const char *str2 = "hello";
        printf("%s and %s is %d\n", str1, str2, own_strcmp(NULL, str2));
        printf("%s and %s is %d\n", str1, str2, strcmp(NULL, str2));
        return 0;
}
```

for strcmp of standard library it use to generate warning. but for my function it is not.

```
rajesh@ideapad:~$ gcc own_strcmp.c
own_strcmp.c: In function ‘main’:
own_strcmp.c:21:2: warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 1) [-Wnonnull]
  printf("%s and %s is %d\n", str1, str2, strcmp(NULL, str2));
  ^
```

Comment: Detecting `null` values reliably would mean the compiler has solved the halting problem. Most unlikely. Why do you expect gcc to be able to? If you want such code generated, C is not your language.

Comment: @DavidBowling I can do that , but i want warning to show to user so that it can be better for my library user.

Comment: @Olaf gcc already generating such warning i want to generate same. can you suggest any manual where  compiler warnings generation techniques will be there

Comment: Note: `NULL` is a macro with a _null pointer constant_. Thus a pointer being `NULL` does not make sense. The correct term is _null pointer_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps declaring the [GCC `nonnull` function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.3/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) is what you are looking for. You can specify that all pointer arguments should be non-null, or you can provide an argument list specifying which arguments should be non-null.

The way I read the docs, if the `nonnull` attribute is declared, it is undefined behavior to pass a null pointer to a non-null parameter. The `-Wnonnull` option must be enabled to get the warning. With warnings enabled, if `NULL` is passed to a non-null parameter, a warning is issued. But, *no warning will be issued for a null pointer variable that is passed*. Thus it is important to handle incorrect input at runtime. Thanks to [@alk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035769/how-to-generate-warning-of-non-null-argument-for-my-custom-function/42036584#comment71253693_42036584) for pointing out this important issue.

It looks like [Clang also supports this attribute](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#nonnull-gnu-nonnull). Clang also has the nullability type qualifier `_Nonnull`, but this is not available in GCC.

I should emphasize that this behavior is not supported in the C Standard, but is rather a compiler extension. For portability you should handle incorrect inputs at runtime with well-designed functions.

Here is your function (the earlier version without `NULL` pointer checks) declared with the attribute. I have added a line that calls `own_strcmp()` with a null pointer variable as well; note that this line does *not* cause a warning to be issued. Also note that calling the Standard Library `strcmp()` with a null pointer variable fails to trigger a warning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int own_strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)__attribute__((nonnull));

int main(void)
{
    const char *str1 = "hello";
    const char *str2 = "hello";
    const char *arg = NULL;

    /* Warning issued for this NULL argument */
    printf("%s and %s is %d\n", str1, str2, own_strcmp(NULL, str2));

    /* No warning issued for the NULL variable arg */
    printf("%s and %s is %d\n", str1, str2, own_strcmp(arg, str2));

    /* No warning issued for strcmp() either */
    printf("%s and %s is %d\n", str1, str2, strcmp(arg, str2));    
    return 0;
}

int own_strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    int i=0;
    while(str1[i] && str2[i]){
        if( str1[i] != str2[i]){
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return str1[i]-str2[i];
}
```

Here is the output after invoking GCC:

```
λ> gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic warning_gcc_42035769.c
warning_gcc_42035769.c: In function ‘main’:
warning_gcc_42035769.c:13:5: warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 1) [-Wnonnull]
     printf("%s and %s is %d\n", str1, str2, own_strcmp(NULL, str2));
     ^
```

Comment: Might wish to add a note that, in standard C, this is not possible.   What you are describing is a gcc (and clang) specific extension.   Other compilers are not required to support it.   In standard C it is better for the function to check/assert non-null arguments, although these are runtime checks.

Comment: @Peter-- yes, I could have been more clear about this. I will update my answer. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: As another note to the OP: This warning mostly will never be issued if you pass variables to the function.

Comment: Dereferencing a _null pointer_ is always UB. That's not a matter of the compiler.

Comment: @Peter: You have to check at run-time anyway. C has no exceptions, so there is no standard way to handle such situations automatically. The attribute only makes (some) sense for functions which typically take a constant, e.g. the format-string of `printf`.

Comment: @Olaf - it is a programmer choice whether to do runtime checks, just as (in this case) it is a programmer choice to seek compile time checks.   The programmer could equally decide the function is permitted to assume that a passed pointer is valid - such as is the case with `strcmp()` - in which case, passing a null pointer simply gives undefined behaviour according to the C standard, and the caller is responsible for ensuring a valid pointer is passed.

Comment: @Peter: A I wrote: it is of little use for most functions just to have constant arguments checked, but variable arguments not. Either one relies on the date being always correct or not, so the user is responsible. Sometimes this sometimes that just confuses the user. I did not comment on a consistent behaviour, as that's not the subject or the question.

Comment: Standard C provides a method for doing this. Declaring a parameter as `T p[static 1]` says that the parameter must point to at least one element of type `T`, *i.e.* must not be null.

Comment: Attribute nonnull is to give the optimizer the hint to remove all NULL checks. It's quite risky, as once those NULL checks are removed in your library, and it gets linked at runtime and NULL passed... SEGV core dump.

Comment: It's safer to not add the attribute nonnull (which will remove any NULL checks), and keep those NULL checks. Most performance is about memory reads, which may even be in cache. So on a 32bit system, reading those 4 bytes isn't really an issue, the RAM speed and cache speed is very fast, you could check 1,000 pointers for NULL, and not notice. Is your code really doing that? Usually input data verification occurs only once, I don't need to check it again. So your input data parser could check for NULL, and then pass to strcmp etc safe in the knowledge you had already checked.

Comment: OP asked about generating compiler warnings; that is the question I answered. WRT the removal of null checks: as I said in my answer (almost 7 years ago), passing a null pointer to a function annotated `nonnull` results in undefined behavior. A compiler might optimize away null checks _inside_ an annotated function, but not a correct null check before the function call. I just wrote a little program to test this, and the null checks were not removed at any optimization level. IAC, these days I think that using `[static 1]` is better, and of course you need null checks.

Answer (score 4):

C has a method for declaring a pointer parameter that must not be null. However, it cannot guarantee that a null pointer is never passed in error. It advises the compiler that it can compile the routine in the expectation that the parameter will never be null, but it does not necessarily prevent calling routines from incorrectly passing null. A compiler may detect some incorrect calls to such a routine and issue warnings or errors about them but fail to detect others.

This is done by the rarely used syntax of putting the `static` keyword inside the parameter declaration:

```
void foo(int p[static 1])
{
    … body of function …
}
```

This says that `p` must provide access to the first element of an array of at least one element, per C 2011 [N1570] 6.7.6.3 7. Since there must be an element where `p` points, `p` may not be null. For example, when this code is compiled:

```
#include <stddef.h>

void foo(int p[static 1])

void bar(void) { foo(NULL); }
```

with Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2) with default switches, the compiler warns:

```
x.c:5:18: warning: null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument
      [-Wnonnull]
void bar(void) { foo(NULL); }
                 ^   ~~~~
x.c:3:14: note: callee declares array parameter as static here
void foo(int p[static 1]) {}
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

However, this code compiles with no warning:

```
#include <stddef.h>

void foo(int p[static 1]) {}

void bar(int *p) { foo(p); }

void baz(void) { bar(NULL); }
```

So it seems this compiler is able to detect that null is incorrectly passed for such a parameter only when it is directly passed.

Comment: Unfortunately this int p[static 1]); is C, not supported by C++

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to put in a check like this in each function that calls private functions to force the callee to check their params.

```
// example follows. note this isn't production code.
// this forces

// declare a function which should never be called.
void _abort_build() __attribute__ ((error("programming error detected")));


// This function is a barrier, obliging all calling code to ensure it never passes nullptr
// it's in effect a contract, stating what is expected.
static void private_api(const char * p)
{

    if(!p)
    {
        _abort_build();
    }

    __builtin_printf("%s\n", p);

}

// note this is just an example
void public_api(const char * p)
{
    // EXAMPLE, this pointer check is needed, the code calling private_api() must check first
    //if(p)
        private_api(p);

    if(!p)
        __builtin_printf("public_api error: called with nullptr\n");
}



int main()
{
    public_api(nullptr);
}

https://godbolt.org/z/43Tjxxz85
```

Comment: OP wanted compiler warnings, not runtime checks.

Comment: Sounds like you may not be familiar  the way attribute error stops the build.  Can use attribute warning too  :) https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html

Comment: I was looking at `if(!p)` which is evaluated at runtime, but there seem to be other problems here. Shouldn't it be `__attribute__ ((error("nullptr detected")))`? In any case this solution relies on dead code elimination; that does not seem reliable, and I can't get a version of your solution to work at all, i.e., it _always_ fails during compilation no matter what is passed to `my_api`.

Comment: added a godbolt link, but saw it doesn't compile  I realized it works in another C++ example, but not in a traditional function. I will try make another example that does actually work!

Comment: This couldn't work for library code, i.e., the compiler can't guarantee that library code won't be called with a null pointer at the time that the library code is compiled so `if(!p)` can't be eliminated. Also remember that the question is tagged [tag:C], not [tag:C++].

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. I updated the example above, it works now in C. You're totally correct to say it relies upon an optimized build and dead code elimination.  For library code, it's correct what you say, the public API must validate and avoid passing bad params to the hidden implementation.   It's not perfect, may help someone.  What is good, is that it is at compile time. avoids lots of costly runtime checks or dumb assert() macros that then terminate with abort() and impact users with a bad experience.

Comment: Did you have ideas how to solve this for the OP?

Comment: OP asked about generating compiler warnings; that is the question I answered. WRT the removal of null checks: as I said in my answer (almost 7 years ago), passing a null pointer to a function annotated `nonnull` results in undefined behavior. A compiler might optimize away null checks _inside_ an annotated function, but not a correct null check before the function call. I just wrote a little program to test this, and the null checks were not removed at any optimization level. IAC, these days I think that using `[static 1]` is better, and of course you need null checks.