# C is it possible to define a type for not NULL pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

Is it possible to define a type for a pointer to an address which is not NULL?

Background:

I am frequently writing functions like -

```
output_type *some_function(input_type *input) {
//confirm input and its members were correctly initialised
if (input == NULL) {
// error handling code
}
if (input->member_which_is_a_pointer == NULL) {
// error handling code
}
...
//return output computed from input
}
```

it would be clearer if the following could be coded instead -

```
output_type *some_function(input_type_not_null *input) {
//return output computed from input
}
```

Comment: I’ve never seen `input_type input[static 1]` in practice, but maybe that…? It gives about the same level of compiler checking as `__attribute__ ((nonnull))`, though.

Comment: @Ryna `input_type` and `output_type` are normally typedef structs in my programs

Comment: [GCC and Clang allow you to declare function attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42036584/6879826) specifying that pointer arguments should not be `NULL`. Doesn't work for variables that happen to be null pointers, though.

Comment: @Ryan `__attribute__ ((nonnull))` doesn't check for `NULL` pointers at run time.  It's merely an assurance on the programmer's part to the compiler that the pointer will never be `NULL`.  It's the *opposite* of what's being asked for here.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Typically when you’re asking for a non-nullable type you want the compiler to check it, not have automatic runtime checks. C is, of course, pretty light on typing – so `nonnull` gives a pretty light level of checking. It serves as documentation too, though.

Comment: @user2309803: I don’t see how being typedefs changes anything?

Comment: @Ryan I'm not sure why you'd say that.  This question's example code has explicit run-time checks in it:  `if (input == NULL) {
// error handling code
}`

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Because the pointer type is nullable, yes. I don’t think the expectation was to get automatic runtime checks. How would a magic runtime-checked non-null type implement `// error handling code`?

Comment: @Ryan OP clearly asked in the expectation that they don't need to do "error handling" on NULL pointers at runtime. The two ideas (`input_type input[static 1]` and `__attribute__ ((nonnull))`) you proposed are not answers to that. What OP asked is not possible in C.

Comment: @P.P.: You don’t have to check for null if you have a non-nullable parameter. `[static 1]` and `__attribute__ ((nonnull))` both *mean* that, and passing a `NULL` to such a function would be incorrect. It’s barely more than convention, but such is C.

Comment: If it were possible to define a type for a pointer to an address which was not `NULL`, what would you expect code to do at run-time when `not_null_pointer *nnp` is assigned a pointer value of `NULL`?

Comment: @chux if the formal parameter's type was `not_null_pointer`, ideally the compiler would error/warn if the actual parameter's type allowed NULL values. Whenever I find myself repetitively writing lots of similar code (in this case checking for NULLs in struct parameter members), I question my own programming style.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR: No.

What you are asking for is, essentially, what in C++ is provided by references. C has no such thing directly (though see below).

Though, even in C++, there is no runtime guarantee that reference is valid. Nothing prevents you from initializing a reference from a null pointer. It's just Undefined Behavior, and it is programmer responsibility to not write code which may do this.

So, solution is to just never have pointers of thia type with NULL value. Using factory function to generate the object always, and always initializing pointer at definition, and wrapping pointer inside struct, and using assert are good tools helping programmer to not fail in this.

---

Edit: Actually [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48830228/1717300) provides a way more-or-less equal to C++ references, in the way that if you have the kind of array parameter described there, then by calling your function, the caller promises parameter will not be NULL pointer. But this is no hard check, and doesn't actually prevent anything, just makes compiler able to warn you a bit more often.

Comment: In standard C, declaring a parameter as `T p[static 1]` says that the parameter must point to at least one element, *i.e.* must not be null.

Comment: @EricPostpischil My 2nd paragraph covers how C++ references can lead to undefined behavior, if initialized badly (note that UB in 2nd comment happens at `*p` already, and having reference involved is irrelevant to that).

Comment: Sorry about the const issue. I commented in a rush. I was responding to the first sentence, which says the OP is seeking C++`s const behavior. But they are not, since C++ dies not provide the desired guarantee. Your aecond paragraph says that, but that rather contradicts the first sentence. So it is indeed not what OP seeks.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, C has a method for declaring a pointer parameter that must not be null. However, it does not provide the behavior you likely desire. It advises the compiler that it can compile the routine in the expectation that the parameter will never be null, but it does not necessarily prevent calling routines from incorrectly passing null. A compiler may detect some incorrect calls to such a routine and issue warnings or errors about them but fail to detect others.

This is done by the rarely used syntax of putting the `static` keyword inside the parameter declaration:

```
void foo(int p[static 1])
{
    … body of function …
}
```

This says that `p` must provide access to the first element of an array of at least one element, per C 2011 [N1570] 6.7.6.3 7. Since there must be an element where `p` points, `p` may not be null. For example, when this code is compiled:

```
#include <stddef.h>

void foo(int p[static 1]);

void bar(void) { foo(NULL); }
```

with Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2) with default switches, the compiler warns:

```
x.c:5:18: warning: null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument
      [-Wnonnull]
void bar(void) { foo(NULL); }
                 ^   ~~~~
x.c:3:14: note: callee declares array parameter as static here
void foo(int p[static 1]) {}
             ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

However, this code compiles with no warning:

```
#include <stddef.h>

void foo(int p[static 1]) {}

void bar(int *p) { foo(p); }

void baz(void) { bar(NULL); }
```

So it seems this compiler is able to detect that null is incorrectly passed for such a parameter only when it is directly passed.

Declaring a parameter with this attribute may have an adverse effect on your code by removing run-time checks that you include in the function. When I compile this:

```
void foo(int p[static 1])
{
    if (!p)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid pointer passed to foo.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

then the compiler removes the `fprintf` and `exit` from the program completely. This is because the compiler knows that `p` must not be null, so `!p` can never be true, so the `fprintf` and `exit` will never be executed in a correct program. So the compiler removes them during optimization.

Comment: This seems unreliable. [This test](https://ideone.com/LXVF98) using Clang 4.0 on Ideone seems to optimize as you describe, but [this one](https://ideone.com/bNrr3Q) using GCC 6.3 on Ideone does not. I don't have Clang installed on my system right now, but when I compiled this code using GCC there were no warnings.

Comment: @DavidBowling: All attempts to have the compiler diagnose bugs are ultimately unreliable. In general, it is generally impossible for a compiler to determine whether a program has a bug or not. The decision hinges on whether it provides value. If something detects some bugs without interfering with productivity, then it is useful.

Comment: Not the solution I was looking for, but a very interesting answer all the same.

Comment: And passing NULL to `void foo(int p[static 1]){}` is undefined behaviour; so does not checking whether the pointer is NULL in `void foo(int *p){}` and proceeding to use (e.g., dereference it). In reality, pointer arguments are not necessarily passed in a simple manner as in `foo(NULL);` for a compiler to detect and issue a diagnostic.

Answer (score 1):

No, not possible. Use attribute nonnull for compile time check and add an assertion in the beginning of the function. Assertion is just one line and helps with debug immensely. Compare:

```
output_type *some_function(nonnull_input_type *input) {
```

and

```
output_type *some_function(NONNUL input_type *input) {
   ASSERT(input);
```

It's not that much to type. Besides ASSERT macro can be redefined to do something meaningful, like longjump to safe frame if your program requires graceful crashes.

Comment: Do you mean `assert()`? I meant custom macros, many projects have a set of, can be called ASSERT, CHECK, DIE and such.

Comment: Yes.  Too early in the morning.  Deleting. :-/

Comment: but can the ASSERT one liner also check the input struct members which are pointers themselves. That's where hierarchical spaghetti starts to creep in.

Comment: if you have a complex check, you'll have to code it in one place or another. If such check is used multiple times just wrap it into a checker function `ASSERT(check_input(input));`. If you use exactly this combination a lot, then you can create a special macro for it, say ASSERT_INPUT. There is always a way to avoid code repetition.

Comment: In standard C, declaring a parameter as `T p[static 1]` says that the parameter must point to at least one element, *i.e.* must not be null.